# Валидация данных передаваемых в процедуру

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Имеется сторонняя система, которая вызывает процедуру на SQL Server.
Проблема в том, что данные могут содержать одинарную кавычку, что вызовет ошибку.

Имеется ли способ от этого защититься (валидировать), чтобы не получать ошибки?

Пример:

```
execute PRC @abc = '{"code": "500 Internal Server Error","status": "'Unable to complete the operation')"}'
```

Разумеется возвратит

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1

Incorrect syntax near 'Unable'.
```

Comment: Процедура ваша? Если да, то почему не проверить строку перед подстановкой ее в SQL запрос?

Comment: вопрос как раз про то, как это сделать)

Answer (score 0):

Просто перед передачей строки выполните функцию ЗАМЕНЫ одной одинарной кавычки на две одинарных кавычки.

Например @abc = ЗАМЕНИТЬ(@abc, "'", "''")

```
execute PRC @abc = '{"code": "500 Internal Server Error","status": "''Unable to complete the operation'')"}'
```